# SwiftLint doesn't recognize changes to .swiftlint.yml (Xcode11.3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, carthage, swiftlint

Trying to install swiftlint using mintfile and carthage.

Xcode version 11.3.1.

Using swiftlint latest version **realm/SwiftLint@0.39.1**.

> Abort trap: 6  mint run swiftlint swiftlint --path ${TARGET_PATH}
>   --config ${SRCROOT}/.swiftlint.yml

Comment: Can you give us more information? How do you run swiftlint? And why do you say about changes to the .yml file? It used to work before?

Comment: @phi it’s working with xcode 10.1 and swift 4.2. Now we have to migrate that project with latest xcode. SwiftLint installed using mintfile. Then after carthage update. And last step mint run xcodgen.